# How to make a connection string for CR 8.5 using VB6.0

Tags: vb6, ms-access-2013, crystal-reports-8.5

I wanted to know how to make a Connection String statement for Crystal Reports 8.5 using Visual Basic 6. I've tried this code:

```
CrystalReport1.ReportFileName = "C:\Report1.rpt"
CrystalReport1.Destination = crptToWindow
CrystalReport1.DiscardSavedData = True
CrystalReport1.Connect ="Data Source=Localhost;UID=sa;PWD=****;DSQ=Dat BdName;"
CrystalReport1.WindowState = crptMaximized
CrystalReport1.Action = 1
```

But I couldn't understand the 4th line. Can someone explain me about this. I am using MS Access 2013 as Database.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some modifications this should work:

```
Public Sub OpenReport(ReportPath As String, DataPath As String)
    ' 1) add a reference to the Crystal Reports 8.5 ActiveX Designer Run Time Library
    ' 2) place a CrystalActiveXReportViewer control named crView to your form
    
    Dim oCRapp As CRAXDRT.Application
    Dim oReport As CRAXDRT.Report
    
    Set oCRapp = New CRAXDRT.Application
    Set oReport = oCRapp.OpenReport(ReportPath, crOpenReportByTempCopy)
    SetReportDatabase oReport, DataPath
    crView.ReportSource = oReport
    crView.ViewReport
End Sub

Public Sub SetReportDatabase(CrystalRpt As CRAXDRT.Report, DataPath As String)

    Dim oTab As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable

    On Error GoTo errhndl

    For Each oTab In CrystalRpt.Database.Tables
        ' check connection type
        If LCase$(oTab.DllName) = "crdb_odbc.dll" Then
            With oTab.ConnectionProperties
                .DeleteAll
                .Add "Connection String", "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" & DataPath & ";Uid=Admin;Pwd=MyPassword"
            End With
        End If
    Next oTab

    ' subreports

    Dim rptObj    As Object, rptObjs As CRAXDRT.ReportObjects, rptSecs As CRAXDRT.Sections, rptSec As CRAXDRT.Section
    Dim subRptObj As CRAXDRT.SubreportObject, oSubTab As CRAXDRT.DatabaseTable
    Dim subRpt    As CRAXDRT.Report

    Set rptSecs = CrystalRpt.Sections

    For Each rptSec In rptSecs
        Set rptObjs = rptSec.ReportObjects

        For Each rptObj In rptObjs
            If rptObj.Kind = crSubreportObject Then
                Set subRptObj = rptObj
                Set subRpt = subRptObj.OpenSubreport

                For Each oSubTab In subRpt.Database.Tables
                    If oSubTab.DllName = "crdb_odbc.dll" Then
                
                        With oSubTab.ConnectionProperties
                            .DeleteAll
                            .Add "Connection String", "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" & DataPath & ";Uid=Admin;Pwd=MyPassword"
                        End With
                    
                    End If
                Next oSubTab
            End If
        Next rptObj
    Next rptSec

    Exit Sub

errhndl:

    Err.Raise Err.Number, "SetReportDatabase", Err.Description

End Sub
```